# How to compare 2 arrays and get number of mutual elements?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 arrays like:

array_A: `[0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1]` which is predicted and

array_B: `[1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0]` is the true labels, thus Array B has 2 classes, 0 and 1.

I would like to compare Array A to Array B but for only once class, let's say 0 for example where the prediction is correct. Visually it gives us 3. I tried with like with
`np.where(array_A==array_B],1,0)`  but it doesn't work.
How should I do this using python ?

Comment: Use `zip()` to pair up the two lists, then loop through them comparing the elements.

Comment: please next time submit your array in python compatible syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a list using a list comprehension over the `zip` of the two input lists.

E.g.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
b = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[x for x, y in zip(a, b) if x == y == 0]
```

Elements from the two lists are only included in this new list if the corresponding elements in each input list are equal, and also are `0`.

The length of the list is the value you want.

```
len([x for x, y in zip(a, b) if x == y == 0])
```